# How did Tagon conceal himself?

Tags: arthdal-chronicles

In *Arthdal Chronicles*, we see that Tagon, the hero of the Arthdal Union who devised the plan of genocide against the Neanthals, is actually

> an Igutu

That of course explains his considerable skill at combat; we've seen that even the Igutu tend to be notably stronger and faster than regular humans. However, we know that Tagon was traveling and fighting with the regular soldiers since he was very young. He apparently had a reputation, not only as a strategist, but also as a fighter; for instance, we saw him kill a subdued Neanthal from a distance. Obviously, had he suffered any wound, even the slightest scratch, it would have showed his purple blood, which would be a definite giveaway. He would also need to constantly wear some kind of concealer on his lips to obscure the purple color, although possibly this would be less notable. And I think if he ever took off his shirt, he'd have some kind of mark on his back.

How did he avoid anyone seeing his blood during this time, or any of the other signs?

Comment: And here I was hoping we'd finally had a new *Schlock Mercenary* question...